# Why is there a scene about the age of consent in "Transformers: Age of Extinction"?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-age-of-extinction

In *Transformers: Age of Extinction*, there is a scene where Jack Reynor's Shane explains to Mark Whalberg's Cade Yeager that it is legal for the former to date/sleep with the latter's daughter. In-universe, Shane is 20 and Cade Yeager's daughter is 17. Apparently, there is a specific law called the "Romeo and Juliet Law" that is applicable to the situation.

Why is this scene in the movie? It confuses me to no end. It is totally superfluous to the plot and only serves to bloat the two hour and forty-five minute movie even more. Was there a producer in a real-life situation that necessitated a law in that vein, one who insisted that this scene be put in the movie? Is it just a bad joke, nothing more?

Comment: you expected logic from *Micheal Bay* ?

Comment: I haven't watched the movie so going off purely the question it seems to just be a joke about the former being able to sleep with the latter's daughter, a wind up.

Comment: Additionally, the R&J law said they could date. There was nothing mentioned about sleeping with a minor.

Comment: It's also a theme that is pretty common in Michael Bay movies (sexualising young/underage women), along with bad racial stereotypes, or explosions. The scene also features a goof, in that the actor quotes a specific statute, but the prop used where this is printed out/laminated has an entirely different number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the actor who played Shane, it was intended to be a funny skit (e.g. rather than a creepy man just explaining why he's dating a child). Notably, it was added after the script was finalised, presumably to 'punch-up' the comedy in the scene.

> “I was 21 years of age, making this huge franchise film, and doing what I was told, because that’s kind of what you do when you get on one of those films,” Reynor explained, noting t**he joke wasn’t in the script initially.**
>
> “When you look at the culture of it now, especially given the advent of the #MeToo era, yeah, it’s definitely **a problematic joke**, but I’m not the writer of the film.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Transformers: Age of Extinction star Jack Reynor revisits that awkward age-gap joke: 'It’s definitely problematic'](https://ew.com/movies/2019/07/05/jack-reynor-transformers-age-of-extinction-joke/)</sup></sub>

The film's producer says that it was intended as ribald humour (about underage sex) and you should just **get over it**.

> **MTV:** *There's also a lengthy scene where you have a joke about Romeo and Juliet laws in Texas, and multiple reviews brought up concerns about that, particularly the content of that scene. In a movie that is based on a toy line, you’re going to get kids coming in, families coming in, was there any discussion about that scene in particular maybe crossing the line?*
>
> **Bonaventura:** Our world has gotten so over concerned about things, that’s my reaction to that. I find that scene funny and I don’t think there’s anything in it that’s so ribald or strange that anybody should have concern.
>
> Look I respect people’s rights to feel that way, but I don’t know, I think it’s a funny scene and it’s intentionally funny. And it’s a real thing at the same time, which is probably what makes it funny you know? It probably makes people feel uncomfortable because it’s something that happens in the real world and we’re just giving it a moment.
>
> I don’t know, I think people take things too seriously. The whole scene [shows] how people look at our world and have a lot of respect. Come on you guys have a little sense of humor.
>
> <sub><sup>['TRANSFORMERS' PRODUCER ANSWERS CRITICS BIGGEST PROBLEMS WITH 'AGE OF EXTINCTION'](http://www.mtv.com/news/1861161/transformers-age-of-extniction-lorenzo-di-bonaventura-interview-critics/)</sup></sub>